# How to make change the height of all images inside a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to make change the height of all images inside a div?

I have

```
$('.images img').each(function() {
      $('img').attr('height', element.parent().attr('imgheight'));
    });

<div imgheight="300px" class="images">
  <img src=" http://www.yu51a5.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/goldenhorseman.jpg " />
  <img src=" http://www.yu51a5.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/bronze-horseman.jpg " />
</div>
```

It does not seem to do anything - see https://jsfiddle.net/yu51a5/527gn64n/4/. How to make it work?

I cannot use "height=100%" because normally these images come with captions, so the image should be shorter that the div.

Comment: why don't you add/remove a css class?

Comment: @Nan: what do you mean?

Comment: I think it is called "custom attribute" and it allowed. Maybe there is a better way to do it, without it.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/527gn64n/7/ How I would fix your solution, but there are already a number of other good solutions so I won't write this in full. (Also, my removed comment was me misunderstanding what you were doing, sorry about that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined `element`. Access the node from inside the each function.

```
$('.images img').each(function(i, node) {
  $('img').attr('height', $(node).parent().attr('imgheight'));
});
```

[Working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/527gn64n/6/)

Comment: Normally there are <div> and <a> in between the container div and img, I have tried to generalise your fiddle but it did not work. Could you help? https://jsfiddle.net/yu51a5/527gn64n/10/

Comment: You misunderstood the params. You don't need this multiple ```el```. The first param is an index and the second the node you are selecting. Do like you did but keep the params like I did first: https://jsfiddle.net/527gn64n/11/

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use HTML5 data- attribute with your custom attribute `imgheight`

```
<div data-imgheight="300px" class="images">
  <img src=" http://www.yu51a5.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/goldenhorseman.jpg " />
  <img src=" http://www.yu51a5.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/bronze-horseman.jpg " />
</div>
```

And JS can be as easy as this:

```
  $('.images > img').css('height', $('.images').data('imgheight'));
```

Check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/527gn64n/5/)

But, if you have multiple `.images` div, you would do like this

```
$('.images img').each(function() {
  $(this).css('height', $(this).closest('.images').data('imgheight'));
});
```

or better

```
$('.images').each(function() {
  $(this).find('img').css('height', $(this).data('imgheight'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `element` to `$(this)` and you're good.

https://jsfiddle.net/wh85afq7/

Answer (score 0):

Change the 2 references within the each function to the images to $(this)...

```
$('.images img').each(function() {
  $(this).css('height', $(this).parent().attr('imgheight'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `data-height` attribute and get value by `element.data("height")`

here is the working example below

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('.images img').each(function() {
       $(this).attr('height',$('.images').data("height"));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-height="300px" class="images">
  <img src="http://www.yu51a5.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/goldenhorseman.jpg" />
  <img src="http://www.yu51a5.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/bronze-horseman.jpg" />
</div>
```